# Regex convert every even character to uppercase - Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a string "test" and I'd like to convert every 2nd character to its uppercase alternative
so "test" would be "tEsT".

I've been trying to capture it using regex but I don't know how to capture 2 groups at the same time (one for even and one for odd characters)

my regex to capture every even character is : .(.?)
my regex to capture every odd character is : (.?).

I need to group the 2 regexes above into one regex with 2 capture groups but I don't know how.

Comment: Try `(.)(.)` -> `$1\u$2`, but perhaps, you want to replace `.` with `\w` or `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: If there're spaces, what must be the result? `test test` --> `tEsT TeSt` or `tEsT tEsT`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])
```

And replace all by this:

```
\1\u\2
```